# Is `Object.fromEntries()` secure from prototype pollution?

Tags: javascript, security, prototype, exploit

Consider the following simple example of prototype pollution in JavaScript:

```js
function sayHello(name) {
  console.log(`Hi ${name}!`);
}

// Pollute the prototype
({}).__proto__.toString = () => alert('hacked');

// Trigger the exploit
sayHello({});
```

I was wondering if a similar exploit could be done with [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries), so I tested:

```js
function sayHello(name) {
  console.log(`Hi ${name}!`);
}

// Try to pollute the prototype, but doesn't work, even for the same object!
const x = Object.fromEntries([['__proto__', { toString: () => alert('hacked') }]]);

// Try to trigger the exploit, but fail
sayHello({}); // Hi [object Object]
sayHello(x); // Hi [object Object]
```

The fact that the built-in `Object.fromEntries` is safe from this exploit is great, I was expecting some protection. However, I thought it would either throw an error or skip setting the `__proto__`, but to my surprise the `__proto__` was actually set!

```
x.__proto__.toString(); // Exploited!
x.toString(); // Not exploited!!
```

I was very surprised that `Object.fromEntries` managed to create an object whose `.__proto__.toString` is exploited while `.toString` is not.

So, is this safe?

**Can I use `Object.fromEntries` with unchecked user-supplied data safely?**

Comment: Do you have a need to allow users to write actual functions to feed into your `Object.fromEntries` call?

Comment: @TKoL No, only strings and other objects, but I didn't want to rely on an assumption that polluting the prototype with strings is safe...

Comment: but `{ toString: () => alert('hacked') }` isn't a string, `"{ toString: () => alert('hacked') }"` is, and that prorbably won't have the issue you're talking about

Comment: If you allow for any of the values in the arrays to be an IIFE, the exploit can be done using something like this: `const x = Object.fromEntries([['prop', (() => Object.prototype.toString = alert('exploited'))()]]);`

Comment: @Titus IIFEs are not applicable to my case, users can just pass an arbitrary value, but not code to be eval-ed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I use `Object.fromEntries` with unchecked user-supplied data safely?

Yes, it will never modify `Object.prototype` by building an object.

> I was very surprised that `Object.fromEntries` managed to create an object whose `.__proto__.toString` is exploited while `.toString` is not.

There's nothing special about `.__proto__` here, it's just a getter/setter property on `Object.prototype`, similar to `hasOwnProperty` or `isPrototypeOf`.

You will notice that `Object.fromEntries` does build an object with an *own* `.__proto__` property, and that `x.__proto__ !== Object.prototype` (although still `Object.getPrototypeOf(x) === Object.prototype`). The inherited property is shadowed.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much! Does this mean I could even mimic this behavior by calling `Object.defineProperty` myself instead of relying on `Object.fromEntries`? If yes, can you please show a quick example on how to use `Object.defineProperty` safely this way?

Comment: @PedroA Yes, sure, `Object.defineProperty({}, "__proto__", {value: …, enumerable: true, configurable: true, writable: true})`

Comment: Awesome, your answer was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much!!

Comment: One last quick question, I've noticed that libraries such as lodash and [dot-prop](https://github.com/sindresorhus/dot-prop#path) ignore setting values for `__proto__` for security reasons... Do you see any reason why they can't just use `Object.defineProperty` instead, as you posted in the last comment?

Comment: I suppose they could, but it might mean that for symmetry they would need to ignore inherited properties for `get`ting values as well and just don't want this. Also, "for security reasons" you would want to avoid creating such objects in the first place, as *other* code (even native methods like `Object.assign`) might misbehave with objects containing own `__proto__` properties.